# Drupal + Commerce - One SKU

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce, commerce

For example I have one product with several atrributes(T-shirt  with various colors and sizes). Can I assign one  SKU for all colors? 
I have asked this question on official forum - but no luck, no answer.
I have posted ticket at Commerce support  - they told me to use the Commerce Customizable Products - I don't no how to use this module.
Maybe somebody have solution? I will  be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The SKUs can never be the same for two products. They should stay unique.

The details can be found on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/54047/10021

P.S. Drupal related questions should go to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe u have only one product called T-Shirt but different product attributes.
so only one sku is allowed for one product u cannot have one 2 sku for same product.
if u want different sku create it as two separate products.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to create an Option set. So you create one product "T-SHIRT" and you have a field option set that allows you to pick the colour of the shirt and another for the size.

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_option

If you need these different options to be different prices, you can also use the pricing attribtues module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_attributes